# ng-repeat to get table with repeat values within inner list | groupBy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a table to display a list of records.

```
{  
"results":[  
  {  
     "name":"result1",
     "values":[  
        {  
           "level":"local",
           "value":12,
           "period":"Q2"
        },
        {  
           "level":"global",
           "value":80,
           "period":"Q1"
        },
        {  
           "level":"global",
           "value":50,
           "period":"Q2"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "name":"result2",
     "values":[  
        {  
           "level":"local",
           "value":52,
           "period":"Q1"
        },
        {  
           "level":"local",
           "value":65,
           "period":"Q2"
        },
        {  
           "level":"global",
           "value":50,
           "period":"Q1"
        }
     ]
  }]
}
```

I want the data to be displayed in below format

```
Name    Level   Q1  Q2
-----------------------
result1 local       12
result1 global  80  50
result2 local   52  65
result2 global  50
```

I'm using `ng-repeat` to obtain this.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.results">
  {{item.name}}
  <div class="col-sm-1" ng-repeat="value in item.values">
    {{value.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above approach both global and local tiers in same row with only one of the values getting picked up. GroupBy value.level doesn't help either.
How do I implement inner grouping in ng-repeat?

Comment: I think you need to flatten and group your array of values before you display it

Comment: I get the data in this structure from ajax call. Do you recommend me to have data in `result1-local-q1-q2; result1-global-q1-q2;result2-local-q1-q2; result2-global-q1-q2` format? I tried to do that but i'm finding it difficult to construct that json. I'll try to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I have used uderscore to achieve desired array here ,so you can use below code :

```
var newArr = [];
var obj = {
    'name': '',
    'level': '',
    'Q1': '',
    'Q2': ''
}
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.vm.results.length; i++) {
    var values = _.groupBy($scope.vm.results[i].values, 'level');
    console.log(values);

     _.each(values, function(val){
            var obj = {
            'name': '',
            'level': '',
            'Q1': '',
            'Q2': ''
        }
               obj.name=$scope.vm.results[i].name;
               obj.level=val.level;
               _.each(val , function(val1){
                   if(val1.period=='Q1'){
                       obj.Q1=val1.value;
                   }else if(val1.period=='Q2'){
                       obj.Q2=val1.value;
                   }
               })

         newArr.push(obj);


     });

}
```

newArr that you receive , just iterate it and use it for you table it will work.